# Matlab Function

Tags: matlab

I wrote this code

```
var1=sqrt(0.2);
var2=sqrt(1);
var3=sqrt(5);


x=-100:1:100;
y=-100:1:100;
z=-100:1:100;

f1=(1/(var1*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((x-0)/var1).^2);
f2=(1/(var2*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((y-0)/var2).^2);
f3=(1/(var1*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((z-0)/var3).^2);
```

However,when I plot those, f1 and  f3 results are like this. I think the top values should not be equal. Could you please give me some advice? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You're using `var1` instead of `var3` in the normalization of your third gaussian. Also I would call your variable something besides `var` since it's actually the standard deviation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your formula, you used

```
f3=(1/(var1*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((z-0)/var3).^2);
```

it should be:

```
f3=(1/(var3*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((z-0)/var3).^2);
```

To avoid such issues, I recommend not to copy/paste code. Instead use a single implementation:

```
npdf=@(v,x)((1/(v*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((x-0)/v).^2))
f1=npdf(sqrt(.2),x)
f2=npdf(sqrt(1),x)
f3=npdf(sqrt(5),x)
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed that